# Connect IntelliJ to Git using Gitkraken

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitkraken

I'm trying to connect IntelliJ to Git. I know that to this end one has to provide the path to the Git executable to IntelliJ, but I cannot find it. I have only downloaded and registered to Gitkraken so far as I thought that would automatically install the executable on my PC. But since I can't find it, I think I might be wrong. Does anybody know if it is possible to connect IntelliJ to Git through Gitkraken only? And if so, how? Or do I have to download Git separately 
Apologies if that is a stupid question but I'm new to Git. 
Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitKraken has no command line Git client in its distribution/installation location. IntelliJ IDEA requires you to install and use the command line `git` executable.

https://git-scm.com/downloads

Answer (score 0):

No, IntelliJ has a built in client.  You would either use that or Gitraken as a separate client GUI.

If Gitraken has a git.exe executable, you need only tell IntelliJ where to find it.

I tell IntelliJ that it can find the Git executable on my Mac at `/usr/bin/git`.   You need to tell IntelliJ where to find it on your machine.